# How to set dynamic version for tool.setuptools_scm in pyproject.toml

Tags: python, ubuntu, setuptools, pyproject.toml, setuptools-scm

I'm trying to test the `pyproject.toml` by building an example.

If I deleted the line "`[tool.setuptools_scm]`", the build will success, but adding that line, the build will fail with the following error.

**Here is the pyproject.toml: /test/example/pyproject.toml**

```
[project]
name = "example"

dynamic = ["version"]

[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
version = {attr = "example.__version__"}

[tool.setuptools_scm]
```

**When building with this command:**

```
# cd /test/example
# python -m build --no-isolation
```

**Here is the error:**

```
* Getting build dependencies for sdist...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
    json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 287, in get_requires_for_build_sdist
    return hook(config_settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 328, in get_requires_for_build_sdist
    return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
    self.run_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
    exec(code, locals())
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 103, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 147, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 303, in __init__
    _Distribution.__init__(self, dist_attrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 283, in __init__
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 654, in finalize_options
    ep(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools_scm/_integration/setuptools.py", line 121, in infer_version
    _assign_version(dist, config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools_scm/_integration/setuptools.py", line 56, in _assign_version
    _version_missing(config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools_scm/_get_version_impl.py", line 112, in _version_missing
    raise LookupError(
LookupError: setuptools-scm was unable to detect version for /test/example.

Make sure you're either building from a fully intact git repository or PyPI tarballs. Most other sources (such as GitHub's tarballs, a git checkout without the .git folder) don't contain the necessary metadata and will not work.

For example, if you're using pip, instead of https://github.com/user/proj/archive/master.zip use git+https://github.com/user/proj.git#egg=proj

ERROR Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_sdist
```

What's the correct configuration for `[tool.setuptools_scm]` in `pyproject.toml`?

Comment: This seems related? https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm/issues/536

Comment: https://setuptools-scm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/ I think you need to remove section `[tool.setuptools.dynamic]` and `version` key in it.

Comment: @JaxkDev Your answer is correct, why did you delete it?

Comment: @phd apologises didn’t mean to must have meant to delete another answer somewhere…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the notes left [here](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm?tab=readme-ov-file#pyprojecttoml-usage)

> To enable version inference, you need to set the version dynamically in the project section of pyproject.toml:

```ini
[project]
# version = "0.0.1"  # Remove any existing version parameter.
dynamic = ["version"]

[tool.setuptools_scm]
```

- Note @phd comment:

> https://setuptools-scm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage I think you need to remove section `[tool.setuptools.dynamic]` and `version` key in it